# How to properly pass a cancellation token when using IHttpClientFactory

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core-3.0

I'm trying to improve the logging of an un-successful `HttpResponseMessage` responses after sending `HttpClient.SendAsync` requests.

Using the `System.Net.Http.IHttpClientFactory` [feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.ihttpclientfactory?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.0) of .net-core this code makes request:

> POST https//fooApp.fooDomain.com/fooMethod
>
> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

startup.cs:

```
services.AddHttpClient("MyHttpClient", client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https//fooApp.fooDomain.com/");
    client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15);
});
```

MyHttpService.cs:

```
public class MyHttpService
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _factory;
    public MyHttpService(IHttpClientFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetHttpResponseMessage(...)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = this._factory.CreateClient("MyHttpClient");

            using (request.HttpContent)
            {

                var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
                {
                    RequestUri = new Uri("fooMethod", UriKind.Relative),
                    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                    Content = new StringContent(string.Empty, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
                };

                using (requestMessage)
                {
                    return await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
                }
            }
        }        
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log the exception...
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when `SendAsync` throws exception (like `TaskCanceledException` or `OperationCanceledException` due to timeout) I would like to look at `IsCancellationRequested` of the cancellation token and log a proper message if true.

My question is how (and where) is it best to create the `CancellationToken` to be passed into the `SendAsync` method? in order to catch it when timeouts occurs. for my understanding the token must be coordinated with the `HttpClient` timeout's timespan that has been initialized at startup.

```
try
{
    //...
    return await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage, cts);
}
catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
{
    if (cts.IsCancellationRequested) //log time-out
    else //log general
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //log general
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to coordinate your manual cancellation token with timeout, or?

Comment: hey @John_ReinstateMonica, I'm not sure I understood your question, I believe yes - I'm trying to coordinate them but I'm not sure if its needed to achieve my goal

Comment: But `cts.IsCancellationRequested` isn't related to `client.Timeout`, right?

Comment: When you pass in your cts, it is to cancel the async request, when your request times out, it gets cancelled, they're not the same thing.

Comment: Hey @JohanP got it. inside service I'll init the token with `cts = new CancellationToken()`, and call `SendAsync(requestMessage, cts);`, it will be catched and the `IsCancellationRequested` will be true.

Comment: @ShaharShokrani I have never created my own cts to pass in, I always use one that was created by the framework, i.e. inside a controller's action method when a request gets aborted.

Comment: @JohanP so now I'm getting a little confused, how to use token that created by the framework? I'm not using controller in this project.

Comment: @Shahar I think Johan thought you were using ASP.NET Core. Anyway, short version is: HttpClient timeout and your cancellation token are two completely separate things. By checking that the cancellation token has requested cancellation, you're not checking if the connection has timed out.

Comment: @ShaharShokrani You can create your cts and pass it in but it's kind of pointless. Whether you do that or use timeout, you will still get a TaskCancelled exception. Just do your logging in your exception handler and not bother with checking if cancellation was requested.